# Assign ID to an option that is dynamically created for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatable

How do i set an attribute for the new select option that i am trying to create? IE  $(option).attr('id','shift_na'); this line doesnt work

```
option = {};
response['shift_timing'].forEach(function (itemData) {
option.label = itemData;
option.value = index_counter;
optionsSP.push(option);
index_counter = index_counter + 1;
option = {};
});
option.label = "NA";
0ption.value = null;
$(option).attr('id','shift_na');
optionsSP.push(option);
editor.field('shift').update(optionsSP);
```

Comment: Lot's of errors/oddities in your code `eg 0ption` - maybe read it and look in console for errors.  There doesn't appear to be a `select` `option` being generated unless it's hidden in your `.update()` method, which is likely what's creating the element - in your code there are no elements to apply an attribute to.

Comment: here option doesn't refer to any element in your code.